# How can I get an Adobe Animate HTML5 canvas to resize to its parent div, not window?

Tags: html, canvas, jquery-animate, adobe, parent

I have an Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas project, which I want to embed into a webpage. Its width is 900px, height 2000px.

I want to make the canvas responsive in such way that its max-width is 900px, and it scales down proportionally in narrower windows.

However, Adobe Animate generates this code which makes the canvas always stretch to the size of the whole window, ignoring its container.

Since I am not very savvy in JS, I wonder if someone could help me tweak the code so that the canvas stretches to fit the width of its container div, not window?

Here is a pen:

https://codepen.io/tinat/pen/NWyWqGY

Or, if it's easier, the html & css I have:

```
<div id="pagecontainer">

    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(153, 204, 204, 1.00); width:900px; height:2000px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="2000" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(153, 204, 204, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:900px; height:2000px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
pagecontainer{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And the JS code Animate generated:

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, 

fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    handleComplete();
}
function handleComplete() {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    exportRoot = new lib.longcontent();
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot); 
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    function makeResponsive(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType) {      
        var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
        resizeCanvas();     
        function resizeCanvas() {           
            var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
            var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
            var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
            if(isResp) {                
                if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                    sRatio = lastS;                
                }               
                else if(!isScale) {                 
                    if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                        sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }               
                else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                    sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
                }           
            }           
            canvas.width = w*pRatio*sRatio;         
            canvas.height = h*pRatio*sRatio;
            canvas.style.width = dom_overlay_container.style.width = anim_container.style.width =  w*sRatio+'px';               
            canvas.style.height = anim_container.style.height = dom_overlay_container.style.height = h*sRatio+'px';
            stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
            stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;           
            lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;     
        }
    }
    makeResponsive(true,'width',true,2);    
    fnStartAnimation();
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using bootstrap classes – no need to touch the js.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="animation_container" class="w-100">
                <canvas id="canvas" class="w-100"></canvas>
                <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="position: absolute; left: -24px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of the code in action: https://wemakemedia.co.uk